# Build deepin-terminal

Tags: git-buildpackage

I have done cloned deepin-terminal source code from github. Now, what should I do if I want to build it and install deepin-terminal into my ubuntu laptop?
Thank you for answer and help, I am really newbie in linux.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any instructions with that repository, but there's a PPA available - so that will be simpler to use: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/05/deepin-terminal-updated-to-latest.html

Comment: @muru I'd add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no instructions with the repository that I could find, but Noobslab have provided a [PPA for Deepin applications](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/deepin-sc) including the terminal. To use it, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deepin-terminal
```

Comment: oh man, that realy help me. Thank you very much.